# Google sheets query highest value

Tags: google-sheets-api

The query that I use to get a single entry in a spreadsheet is as follows:

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1HXQXVlZ-5_3ndSI33W1i_resFYjQwshIaXNUG1Ooxn4/oobt6ix/private/full?sq=nr=18

I am trying to achieve something like this: ?sq=nr=max(nr)

Basically I'm trying to get the the entry with the highest value for "nr".

Can anyone help with this???

Comment: The spreadsheet you provided needs permission. Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: try this link: https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1uwfHW_xuhkly-n0fUvoIvO9tFgbKeEZ8Gzvw6lR46Jk/oobt6ix/private/full?sq=nr=5